# Trying to make a Discord bot send a message that uses multiple randomly chosen words

Tags: discord.py

I wanted to make a Discord bot with discord.py that sends a message made out of randomly chosen predetermined words. I've tried inserting another variable after the first one, but that just gave a syntax error. Here's my code by the way.

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith('f!generate'):
      variable1 = [
        'test',
        'test2',
        'test3',]
      variable2 = [
        'test',
        'test2',
        'test3',]

      await message.channel.send((random.choice(variable1)),(random.choice(variable2)))
```

How to fix the problem?

Comment: Is there an error? What does the bot send?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Messageable.send` only takes 1 positional argument, you're passing 2. Simply add the two strings together and it should work

```py
await message.channel.send(random.choice(variable1) + random.choice(variable2))
```

Comment: I think OP is passing it as a tuple?

Comment: He's passing two tuples